# Data ingestion pipeline for high volume data

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have a requirement where I have to do the following steps.

1. Find the list of users whose data is modified
2. Each user data can run parallel now.

Child steps are:

1. Get the modified data of an user from mongo db(it can be multiple rows)
2. lock them as processing by updating status of those records

3.Transform them. Each row will flattened to 2000 records.

4. Publish to Kafka
5. Update the status to published in mongo db
6. And do some post processing api calls.

The most number of records an user can have in mongo db is 64 and in turn 128,000 messages will be sent to Kafka.

Can anyone suggest better design approach using spring constructs. Does spring batch fits to my use case?

Comment: "1.28 lakh" means 128,000? Please note that we're an international community so try to "translate" or describe any specific words.

Comment: Yes. I have updated

Comment: And stop using offending words: https://www.wired.com/story/tech-confronts-use-labels-master-slave/

Comment: Voted to close since your story is not related to StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your topic is too broad: better to share what you have tried so far rather than asking for a solution from us...

Comment: Apologizes I used it unknowingly as technical architecture word. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: And my query is very specific I guess. I mentioned my algorithm. I can implement in plain way taking complete control of Orchestration and transaction. But my question is does spring batch is suggested way of implemented this pattern?